# How to show log with HEAD index

Tags: git

I would like to show `git log` with `head index`.

For example:

```
commit 0fe2f43f079e4501b6115d18b6e91aea23efa3b7 HEAD~1
commit 0d663a8d39889be306c5fd8090d53fe6e54e1525 HEAD~2
...
commit 27b82baa1281e8346304683554a92e079568d139 HEAD~n
```

Is there any ways to get it?

Thank for any suggestions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not exactly the same, but perhaps this would suffice:

```
git log -g --pretty="commit %H %gd"
```

giving you something like:

```
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD@{0}
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD@{1}
...
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD@{n}
```

---

If you want it exactly as shown you can use `sed` (assuming you have a version of it).

```
git log -g --pretty="commit %H %gd" | sed -e 's/@{/~/g' -e 's/}//g'
```

Should give you the desired:

```
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD~0
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD~1
...
commit 12b09f23d2045bc469c1e0b540c9037bd413b89a HEAD~n
```

Comment: Thank you, but your result have duplicate row :)